# Create recursive table with file structure

Tags: file-io, recursion, io, lua, lua-table

I want to get the file list from a folder recursively in a table.

I tried the following:

```
function getStructure ( path )
    local fileArray = readFilesAndFoldersFromPath( path ) -- returns table
    for i = 1, #fileArray do
        if fileArray[i].type == 'folder' then
            getStructure ( fileArray[i].path )
        end
    end
end
getStructure( '/folder/example')
```

Which works. But now I also want the result in an multidimensional table like this:

```
[1] =>  file1
    =>  file2
[2] =>  folder1
        => file 3
        => file 4
        => folder 2
[3] =>  file 5
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getStructure ( path )
    local fileArray = readFilesAndFoldersFromPath( path ) -- returns table
    for i = 1, #fileArray do
        if fileArray[i].type == 'folder' then
          fileArray[i].folder_content =  getStructure ( fileArray[i].path )
        end
    end
    return fileArray
end

local myFolderStructure = getStructure( '/folder/example')
```